# Cannot execute this command “rasa run actions & rasa shell”

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

Using Rasa open source I tried to execute (Windows Powershell) this command `rasa run action & rasa shell` it generate some error like this:

```
At line:1 char:17
+ rasa run action & rasa shell
+                 ~
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double quotation marks ("&") to      
pass it as part of a string.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerShell you can use a semicolon to run 2 commands (note it should be rasa run actions):

```
rasa shell; rasa run actions
```

In cmd you can still use ampersand.

However this won't work on Windows where commands are run sequentially. One solution is to have a terminal session for each command (you also don't mix up logs and can restart only one if  you need to)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run 2 different commands on the shell. shell does not know "&".

Rasa run command is used to run the rasa framework as a server on localhost:5005

whereas

rasa shell is used to run on the chatbot on the terminal, the server will be started automatically.

I would prefer to run the command in 2 different shell to reduce the debug confusion